# Regular sequence and relations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I read [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/Publications/blowups-and-resolution-apr-2013.pdf) (page 19) the following remark: "If $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ form a regular sequence, their only linear relations over $R$ are the trivial ones, so that:
$$ R\left[\frac{g_1}{g_i},\ldots,\frac{g_k}{g_i}\right]\simeq R[t_1,\ldots,t_k]/(g_it_j-g_j,j=1,\ldots,k)" $$

I can't relate that property to my definition of regular sequence that is $g_i$ regular in $R/(g_1,\ldots,g_{i-1})$. Some help?

Comment: If you believe in the following isomorphism $R[g_1t,\dots,g_kt]\simeq R[T_1,\dots,T_k]/(g_iT_j-g_jT_i)$, then extend it to $R[g_1t,\dots,g_kt][(g_it)^{-1}]\simeq R[T_1,\dots,T_k]/(g_iT_j-g_jT_i)[T_i^{-1}]$, notice that $R[g_1t,\dots,g_kt][(g_it)^{-1}]=R[g_1/g_i,\dots,g_k/g_i][(g_it),(g_it)^{-1}]$ and $R[g_1/g_i,\dots,g_k/g_i]$ is the degree zero component of the ring above. Then identify the degree zero component of the isomorphic ring.

Comment: In fact I wanted to understand the isomorphism that you mention (in the context of blowing up)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the context of blowing-up". This is a property of regular sequences which can be proved inductively and eventually inverting one of the elements of regular sequence.

Comment: I mean that I meet this isomorphism in studying blowing-up.

Comment: I try to prove the identity: case $n=1$ ie $g$ regular is ok

Comment: Case $n\geqslant 2$ not trivial to me... You say to inverting one of the element but to use regularity shouldn't we take a quotient to use the property?

Answer (score 2):

Here's  a proof that the only linear relations are the trivial relations. Proof by induction on $k$. If $k=1$ there are no trivial relations so there is nothing to show. Let's do the  $k=2$ case just to be safe. Suppose 
$a_1g_1+a_2g_2=0$, then $a_1g_1=-a_2g_2$ the map $R/g_1 \to R/g_1$ given by multiplication by $g_2$ sends $\overline{a_2}$ to $0$ and hence (since $g_2$ is regular on $R/g_1$) we have $a_2=rg_1$ for some $r \in R$. So $$0=a_1g_1+a_2g_2 = a_1g_1 + (rg_1)g_2 = (a_1+rg_2)g_1$$ and since $g_1$ is  regular on $R$ we have $a_1+rg_2=0$. Hence $a_1g_1+a_2g_2=0$ becomes $(-rg_2)g_1 + (rg_1)g_2$ and this is a trivial relation.

The induction hypothesis is that for a regular sequence $g_1, \ldots, g_{k-1}$ if we have a relation $a_1g_1 + \cdots + a_{k-1}g_{k-1}=0$, then each $a_i$ is a linear combination $$a_i=\sum_{j \neq i} r_{i,j}g_j$$
with $r_{i,j}=-r_{j,i}$.

Now for the induction step. Now  assume $g_1, \ldots, g_k$ is a regular sequence, and suppose we had a relation $b_1g_1 + \cdots + b_kg_k=0$. The trick is to move the last term $b_kg_k$ to the other side, just like we did in the $k=2$ case. So
$$b_1g_1 + \cdots b_{k-1}g_{k-1}=-b_kg_k$$
and since the map $R/(g_1, \ldots, g_{k-1}) \to R/(g_1, \ldots, g_{k-1})$ given by multiplication by $g_k$ sends $\overline{b_k}$ to $0$ (since $b_kg_k$ is a linear combination of the $g_1, \ldots, g_{k-1}$, and so
$$b_k = c_1g_1 + \ldots c_{k-1}g_{k-1}$$
Substituting this into $b_1g_1 + \cdots + b_kg_k=0$ gives
$$(b_1+c_1g_k)g_1 + \cdots + (b_{k-1}+c_{k-1}g_k)g_{k-1}=0$$
By the induction hypothesis we have for all $1 \leq i \leq k-1$,
$$b_i+c_ig_k = \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^{k-1} r_{i,j}g_j$$ 
with $r_{i,j}=-r_{j,i}$.
So to summarize for all $1 \leq i \leq k-1$,
$$b_i = -c_ig_k + \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^{k-1} r_{i,j}g_j$$ 
and 
for $i=k$ we have
$$b_k = c_1g_1 + \ldots c_{k-1}g_{k-1}$$
which is what we wanted to show.

I don't see immediately the explanation for the second part of the statement you quoted.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thanks

Comment: For the second assertion: it says that via $k[t_i]\to k\left[\frac{g_j}{g_i}\right]_i$ there is no other elements in the kernel than the trivials one. Else we get a polynomial relation so a linear relation with coefficients in $R$ (taking just one $g_j$ from the monomials) and I guess that such relations are not trivial...

Comment: I wait just a little, if someone has a rigorous proof for the second assertion, before validate